# An Error Occurred While serializing to JSON

Tags: json, list, serialization, nhibernate, json.net

Hi firends i'm getting error when i tried to Serialize JSON. I have a model and it have List property;
MyModel:

```
public virtual int Kod { get; set; }
    public virtual string Ad { get; set; }
    public virtual string TrafikKod { get; set; }
    public virtual int TapuKod { get; set; }
    public virtual bool AktifMi { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual IList<TapuIlceModel> IlceList { get; set; }


    public TapuIlModel()
    {
        IlceList = new List<TapuIlceModel>();
    }
```

MyApiController:

```
  [Route("api/TapuZeminApi/GetZemins")]
    [HttpPost]
    public string GetZeminsFromZeminArg(object arg)
    {
        ZeminArg zemArg = SConvert.DeserializeJSON<ZeminArg>(arg.ToString());
       
        List<TapuZeminModel> zeminList = TapuModule.GetZeminListFromArgs(zemArg);
                    

        string jsonResult = SConvert.SerializeJSON(zeminList);
        return jsonResult;
```

Here is a picture about my reciving data error;

[image]

And this my inner exc.;

.{"Error getting value from 'ReadOnly' on 'NHibernate.Proxy.DefaultLazyInitializer'."}

.{"Proxy is detached (i.e, session is null). The read-only/modifiable setting is only accessible when the proxy is associated with an open session."}

What should i do? I need all data... Thanks

when i check again i found something like that:

[image]

Why is there 2 base??? And why name is different? Anyone know?

Comment: The session is already closed, if you will serialize, i recommend use a DTO not the model directly.

Comment: I solved that now i have different problem now. I edited my question. You can check last picture and maybe can tell me why is there two bases?

Comment: When entity is loaded as uninitialized, this is a dynamic object called `Proxy`. The proxy wraps the entity to add additional fuctionality like lazy load feature.

Comment: @Najera
Thank you so much my friend it solved with your comment :)

Comment: Enjoy using NHibernate

Comment: @Najera + CoderWho: Since all of the questions are solved, please consider writing an actual answer, so question can be marked as answered. Otherwise, consider closing or deleting the question.

Answer (score 1):

I geting same error when serilize **SerializeJSON(object)** , i have try JsonConvert.SerializeObject with **JsonSerializerSettings** and **ContractResolver**, it will work.

```
string jsonResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(object, new JsonSerializerSettings() {
            ContractResolver = new NHibernateContractResolver()
        });
```